# Why does my subquery not work on CRUD page of ManyDesigns Portofino?

Tags: hql, crud

I am creating a CRUD page. On that page I am selecting the data from a table depends on the subquery result.
I am using nested query on the page but it is not working.

The query is:

```
from incident as i where i.sysid in(select s.SYSID from sys s, sgroups g, ugroups u 
where s.sid = g.SID and u.GId = g.GId and
 u.ID = %{#securityUtils.subject.principal.asList().get(0)})
```

However, the nested query

```
select s.SYSID from sys s, sgroups g, ugroups u 
where s.sid = g.SID and u.GId = g.GId and
 u.ID = %{#securityUtils.subject.principal.asList().get(0)}
```

is working if it is executed..

Answer (score 2):

You can try to re-write the query differently.
One way is to flatten the query (not using the subquery):

```
select i from incident as i, sys s, sgroups g, ugroups u 
where i.sysid = s.SYSID and s.sid = g.SID and u.GId = g.GId and
u.ID = %{#securityUtils.subject.principal.asList().get(0)}
```

Another way is to use the dot notation to navigate the relationships:

```
from incident as i where i.fk1.fk2.fk3.ID = 
%{#securityUtils.subject.principal.asList().get(0)}
```

Please notice that you must replace fk1/fk2/fk3 with the actual foreign key names (if you have foreign key constraints on the tables). Portofino maps all relationships as properties with the name of the foreign key.

I haven't tested this as I don't have your database. If you need further information, please provide more details: is there an exception stacktrace in the logs? Is the query returning no results?